# entity framework inheritance - retrieve only parent type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I Supplier class:

```
public class Supplier {
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

I have also Subcontractor class and Subcontractor is a Supplier:

```
public class Subcontractor:Supplier {
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

In my db I have Suppliers table with data and another table with id field which is act as foreign key to suppliers table and I have in there also the subcintractor data.

In the entity framework edmx file I declared the inheritance relation:
[image: inheritance]

Now I want to gett all the suppliers which are not subcontractors so I am doing:

```
context.Suppliers.OfType<Supplier>();
```

But this returns also the subcontractors..

How can I get only the Suppliers that are not subcontractors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
context.Suppliers.Where(s => !(s is Subcontractor));
```

**Edit**

If you have more than one class which derives from `Supplier` the only option with LINQ to Entities seems to be something like:

```
context.Suppliers.Where(s => !(s is Subcontractor) 
                          && !(s is DerivedClass2)
                          && !(s is DerivedClass3)); // etc.
```

Entity SQL supports an [ONLY keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399295.aspx) which allows to query for a specific type. But a corresponding counterpart is not available as LINQ operator.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/17/tip-35-how-to-write-oftypeonly-tentity.aspx) is an implementation of an `OfTypeOnly<TEntity>` operator but it makes heavy use of metadata information and manual expression building and might be overkill in simple scenarios.

Comment: What if Subcontractor is just one of 5 types that derived from Supplier?.. Then I'll have to add 5 wheres.

Comment: @Naor: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way, see my Edit above. At least I couldn't find a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use the following LINQ extension, assuming sub-classes are located in the same assembly.

```
public static class MyLinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OfTypeOnly<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        Type type = typeof (T);
        IEnumerable<Type> derivedTypes = Assembly
            .GetAssembly(type)
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(type));

        return query.ExceptTypes(derivedTypes.ToArray());
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> ExceptTypes<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, params Type[] excludedTypes)
    {
        if (excludedTypes == null)
            return query;

        return excludedTypes.Aggregate(query,
            (current, excludedType) => current.Where(entity => entity.GetType() != excludedType));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Get only entities of type Supplier, excluding subclasses.
var suppliers = context.Suppliers.OfTypeOnly<Supplier>();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
context.Suppliers.Where(s => s.GetType() == typeof(Supplier));
```

Comment: It's not working in LINQ to Entities; `GetType` cannot be translated into store expression.